# How to use a query as a control source for a textbox on a form?

Tags: sql, forms, vba, ms-access

I have a form **myForm** that's binded to a table **tbl** in my database. (I don't know if *binded* is the correct term, but It shows records from tbl on by one.)

In the form:

- **contact:** textbox, binded to tbl.contact.
- **dailyCount:** textbox, should show the amount of contacts entered today.

In the table:

- contact
- dateEntry

The query I want to use is:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tbl
WHERE contact = currentContact
AND month(dateEntry)  = month(now) 
AND day(dateEntry)  = day(now) 
AND ear    (dateEntry) = year(now)
```

Where `currentContact` is the contact that is showing on the form now.

1. I tried putting the query in the **dailyCount** dataSource, but It's not working. When I click on the three dots on datasource to access the wizard, I get a window to build functions and not queries.
2. How do I get the **currentContact** showing on the form into the query?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. For a couple of reasons, I don't like to hardcode queries in the datasource of a specific field, and I mostly build/assign all my queries in VBA. So here's how I would do it.

In the load event of you form :

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim RST As Recordset
    dim theCOntact as string ' Change accordingly

    theCOntact = Me.currentContact ' I don't know how your fields are named, so change accordingly

    SQL = "SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM tbl WHERE contact = " & theContact & "' AND month(dateEntry) = month(now) AND day(dateEntry) = day(now) AND Year(dateEntry) = year(now)"

    Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(RST)

    If RST.BOF Then
        dailyCount.Value = RST!cnt
    Else
        dailyCount.Value = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Assuming your contact field is string, if its a number remove the quotes in the SQL

Comment: You don't have to compare against day, month and year. Simply use WHERE dateEntry = Date()

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest approach is to use the [DLookup function](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php) with an associated query:

1. Create and save a named query with your SQL code or equivalent. Let's call it "qryDailyCount". Note that it should be modified to look something like this (in particular, name the column and change the record reference to a GROUP BY for now):

   ```
   SELECT count(*) as DailyCount
   FROM tbl
   WHERE month(dateEntry)  = month(now) 
   AND day(dateEntry)  = day(now) 
   AND year    (dateEntry) = year(now)
   GROUP BY contact
   ```
2. In the dailyCount textbox, set the Control Source to something like this:

   ```
   =DLookUp("Count";"qryDailyCount";"contact = [contact]")
   ```

(Note that if the `contact` field is a text field, you must enclose it with single quotes.)